# Error message "Pivot columns must be comparable"

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a simple code where i am trying to pivot some data. I am getting an error message "Pivot columns must be comparable. The type of column "MX" is "text", which is not comparable."

This is for SQL Server 2017.

```
Select [PROP],M1,M2,M3 from 

(select Prop,Entry, MX from GA_Financial.dbo.tblSAP left join tblMX on GA_Financial.dbo.tblSAP.MDY = tblMX.Datefield) as Tab1

PIVOT
 (
 sum(entry) for MX in (M1,M2,M3)) as TAb2
```

Comment: CAST `MX` to a numeric datatype that can be summed.

Comment: Thanks Tab. Can you perhaps rewrite the code to show me. I am new at this so I will appreciate it much.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another reason to change those deprecated data types into the ones introduced on 2005 (14 years ago). The easiest solution is to cast/convert the column into a comparable data type.

```
SELECT [PROP],M1,M2,M3 
FROM (SELECT Prop,
            Entry,  
            CAST( MX AS varchar(max)) AS MX 
    FROM GA_Financial.dbo.tblSAP AS S
    LEFT JOIN tblMX AS M on S.MDY = M.Datefield) as Tab1
PIVOT(
    SUM(entry) FOR MX  IN (M1,M2,M3)) as TAb2;
```

Always alias your tables, this is important when doing cross-database queries as 4-part and 3-part column names are also deprecated.